# How to use "using static" directive for dynamically generated code?

Tags: c#, roslyn-code-analysis

I want to let the users input mathematics expression in terms of `x` and `y` as natural as possible. For example, instead of typing `Complex.Sin(x)`, I prefer to use just `Sin(x)`.

The following code fails when `Sin(x)`, for example, is defined by the user.

```
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting;
using System;
using System.Numerics;
using static System.Console;
using static System.Numerics.Complex;


namespace MathEvaluator
{
    public class Globals
    {
        public Complex x;
        public Complex y;
    }

    class Program
    {

        async static void JobAsync(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting.Script<Complex> script)
        {
            Complex x = new Complex(1, 0);
            Complex y = new Complex(0, 1);
            try
            {
                var result = await script.RunAsync(new Globals { x = x, y = y });
                WriteLine($"{x} * {y} = {result.ReturnValue}\n");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.Write("Define your expression in x and y: ");
            string expression = Console.ReadLine(); //user input

            var script = CSharpScript.Create<Complex>(expression, globalsType: typeof(Globals));
            script.Compile();

            JobAsync(script);

        }
    }
}
```

## Question

> How to use `using static` directive for dynamically generated code?

Comment: Maybe you should write your own parser for user-input code anyway, and that way, you can easily map the functions to something else.

Comment: `ScriptOptions.Default.WithImports`. Also, you might want to look at some good practices for working with `await`, or you might get some nasty surprises (e.g. `async void` is generally a bad idea).

Comment: @Luaan: Thanks. I am not familiar with asynchronous programming in c#. If you think you can improve it, feel free to post it as an answer. I really appreciate it and of course I will up vote it. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can supply script options to the `Create` function that define the references and imports that should be set for your script:

```
var scriptOptions = ScriptOptions.Default
    .WithReferences("System.Numerics")
    .WithImports("System.Numerics.Complex");

var script = CSharpScript.Create<Complex>(expression, options: scriptOptions, globalsType: typeof(Globals));
```

That way, you can use `Sin(x)` in the input:

> ```
> Define your expression in x and y: Sin(x)
> (1, 0) * (0, 1) = (0,841470984807897, 0)
> ```

However, when dealing with user input, you should consider writing your own parser. This allows you on one hand to define your own “aliases” for functions (e.g. a lower case `sin`) or even a more lenient syntax; on the other hand, it also adds more security because right now, nothing prevents me from doing this:

> ```
> Define your expression in x and y: System.Console.WriteLine("I hacked this calculator!")
> I hacked this calculator!
> (1, 0) * (0, 1) = (0, 0)
> ```

---

I created a quick (and dirty) parser using Roslyn’s syntax tree parsing. Obviously this is rather limited (e.g. since it requires all return values of subexpressions to be `Complex`), but this could give you an idea of how this could work:

```
void Main()
{
    string input = "y + 3 * Sin(x)";
    var options = CSharpParseOptions.Default.WithKind(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SourceCodeKind.Script);
    var expression = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(input, options).GetRoot().DescendantNodes().OfType<ExpressionStatementSyntax>().FirstOrDefault()?.Expression;

    Console.WriteLine(EvaluateExpression(expression));
}

Complex EvaluateExpression(ExpressionSyntax expr)
{
    if (expr is BinaryExpressionSyntax)
    {
        var binExpr = (BinaryExpressionSyntax)expr;
        var left = EvaluateExpression(binExpr.Left);
        var right = EvaluateExpression(binExpr.Right);

        switch (binExpr.OperatorToken.ValueText)
        {
            case "+":
                return left + right;
            case "-":
                return left - right;
            case "*":
                return left * right;
            case "/":
                return left / right;
            default:
                throw new NotSupportedException(binExpr.OperatorToken.ValueText);
        }
    }
    else if (expr is IdentifierNameSyntax)
    {
        return GetValue(((IdentifierNameSyntax)expr).Identifier.ValueText);
    }
    else if (expr is LiteralExpressionSyntax)
    {
        var value = ((LiteralExpressionSyntax)expr).Token.Value;
        return float.Parse(value.ToString());
    }
    else if (expr is InvocationExpressionSyntax)
    {
        var invocExpr = (InvocationExpressionSyntax)expr;
        var args = invocExpr.ArgumentList.Arguments.Select(arg => EvaluateExpression(arg.Expression)).ToArray();
        return Call(((IdentifierNameSyntax)invocExpr.Expression).Identifier.ValueText, args);
    }
    else
        throw new NotSupportedException(expr.GetType().Name);
}

Complex Call(string identifier, Complex[] args)
{
    switch (identifier.ToLower())
    {
        case "sin":
            return Complex.Sin(args[0]);
        default:
            throw new NotImplementedException(identifier);
    }
}

Complex GetValue(string identifier)
{
    switch (identifier)
    {
        case "x":
            return new Complex(1, 0);
        case "y":
            return new Complex(0, 1);
        default:
            throw new ArgumentException("Identifier not found", nameof(identifier));
    }
}
```